# Contract compilation problem with hardhat

Tags: hardhat

hello I'm trying to compile a contract with hardhat but I get the following error

```
HH409:Trying to import @openzeppelin/contracts/access/ownable.sol from contracts/SimpleStorage.sol, but it has an incorrect casing.
```

Here is my  import:
`import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/ownable.sol";`.

Then while searching the forums I am offered another import which is the following: `./interfaces/univ3/IUniswapV3Helper.sol`; but at this moment I get another error which is

```
error HH404 File ./interfaces/univ3/IUniswapV3Helper.sol, imported from contracts/SimpleStorage.sol, not found;
```

Could you tell me what I'm not doing well, thank you.

Solidity v0.8.24

Hardhat v2.20.1

node v18.16.0

yarn v1.22.21

.

Answer (score 0):

The error speaks for itself, "*but it has an incorrect casing*".

This means the import should be:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

Just the word Ownable starts with a capital O, not the small one.

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but `IUniswapHelper` is a different interface, completely different from `Ownable`. That's not an alternative for `Ownable`.

And if you want to use that interface you need to have it inside your directory. Do share more information about your goal, for a better explanation.